# Problem with steam on lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, steam

Pretty simple problem - steam installed, then a thing came up saying it need to install more files.

It runs, and then at the end tells me things are missing from my 32x library? If you need more info I'll try to answer any ques you have

Comment: Yes, we need way more detail than this... an exact error message and a detailed description of what happens would help. For now voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Of course we need more info. "a _thing_ came up"? "things are missing"? Put yourself in our position, would you be able to understand the problem with that information? Please [edit] your question and include the _exact_ errors you get. Also tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using and whether it is 32 or 64 bits. Tell us what you're doing when this "thing" comes up. Give us _something_ to go on!

Comment: I was assuming it was a common problem, and it was because someone answered it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install unmet dependencies using

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I'm completely new to Linux, I put this in 'Run' but it did nothing. I assume i wrote it in the wrong place.

Comment: type this in terminal (Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** to open terminal. Type all commands here)